# How to use dart sass in python

Tags: python, django, sass, dart-sass

Is there any python library to compile sass which uses the [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) implementation?

Currently I am using the [libsass-python](https://pypi.org/project/libsass/) library. But [Libsass](https://sass-lang.com/libsass) is now deprecated

Which is the current best choice to compile sass in python?

Answer (score 0):

SASS is not language specific anymore, you don't need to use npm, yarn or pip to compile sass. Now it works kind of same way how you use Python's Interpretter.

Download the SASS compiler from here for your operating system -

https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.52.1

Now extract the dart-sass folder form the compressed file and move it to desired location.

In my case it was :

`C:\Users\vikas\development\dart-sass`

Now add the location of your dart-sass folder to path.

Search on Internet how to add a location to path for your operating system.

Hope this helps.

Edit : To compile you have to use Terminal.

Use the following command :
`sass ./source_file.scss ./build/output_file.css`

Comment: But it would be great if there was a wrapper python package like in ruby there are https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails, https://github.com/ayushn21/dartsass-ruby. Unfortunately there is no such currently available packages in python.

Comment: Sass developers can't write a wrapper for every language because it results in too much legacy code. This would create problems in future, so they just created a simple compiler in dart which will is and will be future Sass.